# How to set generic CSP header in config.neon?

Tags: php, content-security-policy, neon, nette

I need to set Content Security Policy in `config.neon` file.
The policy for images should look something like this (very stripped down version) `img-src data:`

The server runs PHP/Nette framework, configuration is in .neon files. 
The string `data:` produces syntax error on server-side, because `:` has special meaning in .neon.

```
Nette\Neon\Exception
Unexpected ':' on line 28, column 343.
```

How to overcome this? How can I send "data:" in header?

Comment: I am not not a PHP developer, so this might be trivial for someone working in PHP

Comment: I think your `neon` tag is off the place.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer. The whole definition has to be wrapped in double quotes, then Nette sends it down as it is, without trying to interpret the string

So the correct definition is

```
Content-Security-Policy:  "img-src whatever-is-in-the-double-quotes"
```